# I've a vector from which I want to select its elements that aren't divisible by 3 nor 5

Tags: r

I've the following vector:

```
set.seed(1)
v2 <- sample(1:200,50)
```

I've been trying to select all numbers that are not divisible by 3 nor 5 but I haven't had success

```
nodivisibles <- function(v2){
  prueba <- (v2%%3==0)
  tres <- v2[-prueba]
  pruebados <- (v2%%5==0)
  cinco <- v2[-pruebados]
  list(tres,cinco)
}
```

Comment: Try `v2[!prueba]`

Comment: `v2%%3==0` returns a `TRUE/FALSE` vector, but `-FALSE != TRUE`, it equals zero.

Comment: To invert a boolean you need `!` (i.e. "not")

Comment: Or just use `!=`

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned use `!` to invert.
You can do it in one line without the function.
`v2[!(v2%%3==0 | v2%%5==0)]`

```
# > v2[!(v2%%3==0 | v2%%5==0)]
# [1] 179 176 184 128 121 196  34 133 182 169  38 116  23  68  67  59  82  83  
# 32 131 118 173 103 124   4  74 112
```